# Cual es la tecla de teclado latinoamericano para plantilla de cadena de texto

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría saber como teclear `` este símbolo del teclado que se usa en javascript para las plantillas de cadena de texto. Cada que necesito usarlas tengo que buscar una muestra en google y copiarla para poderla usar pues no se cual es la tecla o combinación de teclas necesarias para escribirlas.

He buscado en google muchas veces y no hay resultados que den esta respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se llama Grave accent, y puedes ponerla con el código ASCII que es presionando alt y tecleando 96, o también puedes intentar con &#96 escribiendolo en tu documento.
Ejemplo

```html
<p>&#96 hola mundo</p>
```

Comment: Excelente! Es lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente no conozco la tecla, pero puedes usar:

> <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd>

o usa el mapa de caracteres - busca "acento grave".

[image: acento grave]